# Creating a stored procedure that would let me do calculations and insert values into tempTable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have started working on a stored procedure to deal with some calculations I need to do. The gist of it is this:

```
Create Table #Temp 
(
    ClientName varchar,
    ClientAddress varchar,
    Units1 int,
    Units2 int,
    UnitsUsed int,
    UnitsSpec int
)

Insert into #Temp (ClientName, ClientAddress, Units1, Units2)
    Select 
        x.ClientName, x.ClientAddress, y.Units1, y.Units2 
    From
        tblClients x 
    Left Join 
        tblClientUnits y On x.clientId = y.clientid
```

The select statement is a bit more complicated, I'm trying to simplify it for readability purposes.

Everything up to here works, so I create a temp table, insert all the info, what I'm trying to do now is for these last 2 columns in the #Temp table, I need to do some calculations, so I'm trying to somehow re-insert into the temp table `UnitsUsed` which would be total of Units1 + Units2, and do the same thing for UnitsSpecwhich would be Units1 + Units2 / 3

What would be a good way to do this? Is this doable?

Edit sample data - desired end result:

```
ClientName     ClientAddress    Units1     Units2    UnitsUsed    UnitsSpec
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bob S          11 Jude Lane     10         20        30           10
```

Comment: You can run the UPDATE command after your INSERT. So ... insert your initial data, then UPDATE #Temp to modify the last two fields with the existing data from your INSERT.

Comment: @Paurian sorry TYPO

Comment: add some sample data and the expected output please...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use - otherwise your column will be limited to **exactly ONE character** - typically this is not what you want .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your INSERT statement, run the UPDATE statement like this:

```
UPDATE #Temp SET UnitsUsed = Units1 + Units2, UnitsSpec = Units1 + (Units2 / 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it at the same time as the other insert

```
Create Table #Temp (
    ClientName varchar,
    ClientAddress varchar,
    Units1 int,
    Units2 int,
    UnitsUsed int,
    UnitsSpec int
)

Insert into #Temp (
    ClientName,
    ClientAddress,
    Units1,
    Units2,
    UnitsUsed,
    UnitsSpec
)
Select x.ClientName
    , x.ClientAddress
    , y.Units1
    , y.Units2 
    , (y.Units1 + y.Units2)
    , (y.Units1 + y.Units2) /3
from tblClients x 
    left join tblClientUnits y on x.clientId = y.clientid
```

Comment: While your first sentence is correct, your code would result in a syntax error.

Comment: I can see possible loss of data with the rounding of the divide. Where's the syntax error?

Comment: In your insert, you've put the calculations in the column list instead of in the SELECT.

Comment: If I wanted forexample UnitsSpec as percentage with 2 decimal point how would I do that?

Comment: You'd convert UnitsSpec to a Numeric. What would UnitsSpec be a percentage of?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the word "re-insert" with the word "update" in your thinking.

Or just do the calculations in your initial INSERT..SELECT.